# How to measure outbound data used by each user ( customer )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am a student and new to AWS services.
I am working on a web-based project.
in the server part (AWS ). I need to monitor the outbound data used by each customer. and generate a bill based on the data used by that customer ( Not AWS billing ).
how I do that which AWS service fit for that please help me.

Comment: There is no existing capability to monitor "data per user", so your application would need to somehow track such usage. From where is the data being served (S3, EC2)? Is the data private or public? That is, can people access it via a URL, or do they need to authenticate to access the data? How do you define and identify a "customer"?

Comment: There is no technical way to do that with AWS, especially if you're serving your website through CloudFront or other CDN service. You can add BI events and edit the headers and responses, but I don't think that is your direction

Answer (score 0):

The best and quickest technical way is to pass each customer through a dedicated LB. It has additional costs and maintenance, but overall if you're not planning to invest in a BI infrastructure and apply your own logic serving sites, that is your direction.

Measuring the traffic through each LB will be quite easy if it's tagged properly (once you enable the cost allocation tags in the billing service)